# Find global references in nested functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, cpython, nested-function

Consider the following nested function:

```
def outer_func():
    def inner_func():
        return [pickle for _ in []]
    inner_func()
```

I want to find all the global references within `outer_func`. A correct implementation would find `pickle`. Following is how I do it in Python 2.

```
outer_func.__code__.co_consts[1].co_names
```

However, this fails in Python 3 as `co_names` of inner_func code object is empty. This happens when the global reference is in a list comprehension. **Can someone explain the reason?**

Following snippet shows difference between Python 2.7 and 3.7.

```
import pickle    

def outer_func():
    def inner_func():
        return [pickle for _ in []]
    inner_func()

inner_func_code = outer_func.__code__.co_consts[1]
print("inner_func_code = {!r}".format(inner_func_code))
print("inner_func_code.co_names = {!r}".format(inner_func_code.co_names))
print("inner_func_code.co_code = {!r}".format(inner_func_code.co_code))
```

Python 2.7.16:

```
inner_func_code = <code object inner_func at 0x7f46f0bf8eb0, file "/path/to/test.py", line 20>
inner_func_code.co_names = ('pickle',)
inner_func_code.co_code = 'g\x00\x00g\x00\x00D]\x0c\x00}\x00\x00t\x00\x00^\x02\x00q\x07\x00S'
```

Python 3.7.14:

```
inner_func_code = <code object inner_func at 0x7f46f0bf8eb0, file "/path/to/test.py", line 20>
inner_func_code.co_names = ()
inner_func_code.co_code = b'd\x01d\x02\x84\x00d\x03D\x00\x83\x01S\x00'
```

Comment: Maybe python 2.7 is mistaken and python 3 has the right idea that `pickle` is actually the name of a local variable inside a list comprehension.